# How do I stop this cascading delete from happening in Django?

Tags: python, database, django, model

I have three model classes in a Django app:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
  ...
  folder = models.ForeignKey('Folder',null=True,blank=True,related_name='folders')
  front_thumbnail_image = models.ForeignKey('Image',verbose_name='Front Thumbnail',null=True,blank=True,related_name='front_thumbnail_for_folders')
  middle_thumbnail_image = models.ForeignKey('Image',verbose_name='Middle Thumbnail',null=True,blank=True,related_name='middle_thumbnail_for_folders')
  back_thumbnail_image = models.ForeignKey('Image',verbose_name='Back Thumbnail',null=True,blank=True,related_name='back_thumbnail_for_folders')

class Image(models.Model):
  ...
  folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder,related_name='images',null=True)

class ImageRepresentation(models.Model):
  ...
  image = models.ForeignKey(Image, related_name="image_representations")
```

Given this model, when I delete an `Image` in the admin site, I would expect the `ImageRepresentation`s associated with that `Image` to be deleted as well, and the `Folder` enclosing that `Image` to be left alone.

The admin site tells me that the enclosing `Folder` will be deleted as well. What can I do to get the desired behavior? I looked into delete cascade rules, but nothing I tried seemed to work.

**Edited** to add three foreign keys on `Folder` (the thumbnail image ones)... I totally overlooked those (obviously). There are no other relationships, honest.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Do you have a `Foreignkey` from `Folder` to `Image` or `ImageRepresentation`?

Comment: You are totally right. I cannot believe I overlooked that.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco If you want to provide the obvious answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create the `ForeignKey`, what gets deleted when the parent object is deleted is controlled by [the `on_delete` parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

By default, `on_delete` is set to `models.CASCADE`, which will delete children objects when the parent is deleted. None of the other configuration options can create the behavior you are reporting here.

Do you have a `Foreignkey` from `Folder` to `Image` or `ImageRepresentation`? (folder thumbnail in your case)

Comment: @HiltonCampbell Sometimes you need someone to point out the obvious : )

Comment: Not anymore with django 2.0. On_delete is no more an optional parameter

Answer (score 17):

As Thomas has said, the default `on_delete` behaviour of a `ForeignKey` is `models.CASCADE`. Implying the 'child' model will be deleted when the 'parent' model is deleted.

A simple solution would be to include `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` to each of the `ForeignKey` to `Image` fields of the `Folder` model like so:

```
front_thumbnail_image  = models.ForeignKey('Image',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, ...)
middle_thumbnail_image = models.ForeignKey('Image',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, ...)
back_thumbnail_image   = models.ForeignKey('Image',on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, ...)
```