# Django, How to not delete related object (forignkey related) when parent is deleted

Tags: python, django

I have a user model refers as `User` and Product model. When user delete himself,I dont want the related objects to be deleted.

Is there any vulnerabilities in the below code ?

```
class Product(models.Model)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Or is the below code is correct ?

```
 class Product(models.Model)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) and compare which value fits your use-case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I stop this cascading delete from happening in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747886/how-do-i-stop-this-cascading-delete-from-happening-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like this
`on_delete = models.SET_NULL`